# Python: conditional statement and function definition

Tags: python

I am using conditional statement in a function to ask weather an input is float/string/integer and display certain output if it determine each of the input but the input are all taken as string, how to tell the program to identify each input as string/float/integer?

this is the code below;

```
def strl(name):
    lname = len(name)
    return lname

name = input('please enter your name: ')
if type(name) == int:
    print("sorry, integars don't have a length")
elif type(name) == float:
    print('sorry, float do not have length ')
else:
    print(strl(name))
    print(type(name))
```

Comment: `input()` return type is always `str`, it's up to you to [check it and] cast it to the right type

Comment: The `strl` function is entirely superfluous and can be replaced by just `len`.

Comment: Essentially you can't use `type()` as you've discovered. You'll need to validate variable `name` through some other means if validation is needed. This is where most folks turn to regex. Just stop thinking about this as testing for "type" and start thinking about this as testing for the pattern of string you are expecting (like only alphas and spaces and apostrophes, for instance).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use one `try` block to try convert **string** to **int** if this is not possible use another `try` block to try convert **string** to **float** if this also not possible we know this input is a **string** and **length** is printable.

[image: Diagram]

```
def strl(name):
    lname = len(name)
    return lname

name = input('please enter your name: ')

try:
    int(name)
    print("sorry, integars don't have a length")
except:
    try:
        float(name)
        print('sorry, float do not have length ')
    except:
        print(strl(name))
        print(type(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is not clear to me. Anyway, maybe you can use something like this:

```
try:
    float(name)
    print("sorry numbers don't have length")
except:
    print(len(name))
    print(type(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

The input function in python always returns a string.
You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

If you want to check whether or not the string contains a number, you can use the `int()` function to convert the string to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

All the information that you get to *input()* function is always **string**. It could be info like: 123, True, [1,2,3]. All of them will be convert to string automatically. You can use *len()* function to any string, even if it contains only numbers. You can also use *string_name.isdigit()* function to check, maybe your string contains only digits.

Comment: The won’t be “converted to string“, they simply *are* strings. They were never not strings to begin with. Just as “[1,2,3]” in your answer isn’t a list.